# Diagonal Tensor

Tags: tensor-calculus

I want to do some calculations for anisotropic properties. The software I am using only takes a tensor matrix as an input. Now to my question. I have 3 literature parameters for the properties along each axis x y z. Is it correct that the tensor matrix would simply be a diagonal matrix?

Sorry for this stupid question, I just want to walk safely.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the physical scenario you are modeling?

Comment: I want to calculate poisson's equation for a given space charge density within a semiconductor. For that I found a parallel permittivity of 10.16 and perpendicular one of 9.29. And now I wanted to define the tensor for these two perimittivity values.